# Buffer reader issue in Java

Tags: java, integer

I am beginner of Java . When i ran the below program
Adding the below code

Got the below error

```
   import java.io.*;
    public class Main
    {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
           {
                InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
                int a;
                int b;
                int c;
                double d=0;
                System.out.println("Enter the values of a, b and c");
                a=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                b=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                c=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                d=b*b-4*a*c;
                if(d>0)
                       System.out.println("Roots are real and unequal");
                if(d==0)
                       System.out.println("Roots are real and equal");
                if(d<0)
                       System.out.println("Roots are imaginary and unequal");   
            
            }
    }
```

I got the below error, need help on this

```
Got the below error 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:614)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Where are you running this? Do you have a console to enter input?

Comment: We are running the program in BlueJ, There is an Input Console.The error is coming for in.readLine()

Comment: You need to enter each input separately followed by Enter. Sometimes IDEs are not good at this

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with buffering. Read the error.